# Is there a term for a function which is not continuous on any open set?

Tags: real-analysis, terminology

A function is said to be *nowhere continuous* if it is not continuous at any point of its domain.  Is there a similar term encompassing functions like
$$f(x) = \begin{cases} x & \text{ if } x \in \mathbb{Q,} \\ -x & \text{otherwise.}\end{cases}$$
which may be continuous at some points but which are not continuous on any open set?

Comment: no, and creating too many terms is not a good idea

Comment: (nowhere continuous except at $x=0$)

Comment: (nowhere uniformly continuous)

Comment: "Nowhere uniformly continuous" doesn't make sense, as we don't speak of a function being uniformly continuous at a point, and of course "nowhere continuous except at $x=0$" is not the same thing.  If I wanted to construct a term that actually made sense I could say "with nowhere dense continuous locus."  But if there's an existing term that's used somewhere -- and I'm not sure why I should believe your unilateral claim that there isn't -- then it's best to use it, for the sake of search engines and so forth.

Comment: (I say "continuous locus" by analogy with "smooth locus," although it appears that much more loquacious terms like "set of continuity points" or "set of points of continuity" are more common.)

Comment: Discontinuous almost everywhere?

Comment: if a function $\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ is continuous on a (non-empty) open $U \subset \mathbb{R}$, then it is continuous on an interval $[a,b]  \subset U$ and hence it is uniformly continuous on $[a,b]$. that's why "nowhere uniformly continuous" precisely means "not continuous on any open"

Comment: @Semiclassical: That's a strictly stronger property.  E.g. Thomae's function isn't continuous on any open set, but it's discontinuous on a set of measure zero.

Comment: (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heine%E2%80%93Cantor_theorem )

Comment: @user1952009: Throughout mathematics, "nowhere X" means "not having the property X at any point," where X is a property that happens at a point.  Since we don't say that a function is uniformly continuous at a point, this doesn't really fit the accepted pattern for using the word "nowhere."

Answer (score 1):

We could say that $f$ is locally continuous at $x\in$ dom$(f)$ to mean that $f$ is continuous on a nbhd of $x.$ So we could refer to a nowhere-locally-continuous function. But it is not more useful than to say that the function is not  continuous on any open set.

Comment: It's not a bad little kludge, but I'm more interested to see if there's a term already appearing the literature.

Comment: Maybe in German, which is a nice language for math, as you can easily stick  words together without hyphens to form terms.